# Unexpectedly tokens get revoked in google API showing error as 'Invalid grant'

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am using a google client to provision users with google drive using oauth2 tokens and it will be generating an access token and the refresh tokens while authentication. I have created a refresh flow in my system to refresh my access token when it gets expired. But after certain timestamp the api shown the error as: 'invalid_grant'

```
Returned non success error code with error{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

I can see its happening for multiple users but not at the same time. I tried to digging this issue but couldn't find the cause of this. Can anyone please in this?

I am using webclient for below requests...

auth request as:

```
GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?approval_prompt=force&access_type=offline&client_id=${CLIENTID}&redirect_uri=${RETURNURL}&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly&state=${DATACONNECTION.STATE}
```

And token request is:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=<code>&redirect_uri=<redirect_url>&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>
```

The refresh_token request is:

```
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?refresh_token=<refresh_token>&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&grant_type=refresh_token
```

I am using API to poll the data as:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives?pageSize=4&pageToken=
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant parts of the code you're using?

Comment: You can edit your question and add your code there. Also, provide the code related to the authentication process you're following.

Comment: Hi @lamblichus,
I have added all the requests that I have used for authentication in above question. I am using webclient to hit those request.

Comment: Is is due to the number of refresh_token limitations. But I don't think we have created connection more than 50 times.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the authorization flow you're following right now. With the first request you should be able to retrieve the authorization code (even though the documented URL is `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth`). And with that you could make [this request](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#exchange-authorization-code) to get both the `access_token` and the `refresh_token`. Instead, you are providing the `refresh_token` as a parameter in your third request (you should provide `code` instead).

Comment: Also, you didn't add the request you're making to Drive API. [Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#example) you can see a complete example using flask, I'd suggest you to take a look at it.

Comment: But in the first request anyway we are getting refresh_token and access token. So whenever our access token gets expired we can use the refresh_token to get the new access token and the third request is doing same. While if we need to pass the code every time, we need user consent everytime the token expired, which is not the better approach if we already have refresh token, I guess.

Comment: True, I missed that. Can you provide information on how are you handling the responses from the successive requests? (how you're handling the retrieved refresh and the access_token, including how you are specifying the access_token in your call to Drive API).

Comment: I am saving the refresh token and the access token in my db for a particular user and using that access token I will hit the below API:
```curl --location --request GET 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes?pageSize=100&changeType=file&pageToken=1' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <access_token>```
So incase there is 401 error response in above request, it will call my retry when strategy where I am calling a webclient to hit google's refresh token API (third request which I mentioned in my question) and again saving the access tokens to db.

Comment: The fact that this is failing after some time makes me think this is a problem of getting a new access token based on your refresh token. Do you have a code you're working on? If that's the case, can you provide the relevant parts of it?